# why html output and browser output are different when we encode the user's input data with htmlentities to prevent cross site scripting?

Tags: php, xss

To prevent cross site scripting I am using htmlentities.But I have small doubt in the output of the code.It is

```
$str = "Albert Einstein said: 'E=MC²'";
$enc = htmlenities($str);
```

With this code I am encoding the user's input data.So the variable $enc will be

```
Albert Einstein said: 'E=MC&sup2;'<br>
```

But when this code is rendered and giving output the output will be

```
Albert Einstein said: 'E=MC²'
```

My doubt is we haven't decoded $enc the output should be displayed as

```
Albert Einstein said: 'E=MC&sup2;'<br>
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: The browser know how to interpret HTML, and `&sup2` is a HTML entity. Same as `<br>` is interpreted to be a new line by the browser.

Comment: When you say the _output_, to what are you referring?  The HTML output?  A log file?  The console?  If the HTML, then it will faithfully render the HTML encoded entities to their presentable alternatives.

Comment: Did you actually try the code in your question? Once the typo is fixed the value of `$enc` is empty after running the code. There is nothing in that string that needs to be encoded from what I can see.

Answer (score 0):

> Some characters are reserved in HTML.

Assume that we want to write something in HTML to show an image.

Then we will write `<img src="someimage.jpg" />` and the browser loads and renders the image in the page.

Now consider we have a learning website and we want to teach our audiences how to load an image in a web page. so what should we do now?

To display these reserved characters we need to use HTML entities, and browser will handle it for us.

> Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities.
>
> Characters that are not present on your keyboard can also be replaced
> by entities.

You can read about it in w3schools - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp.